# Playing Queue/Playlists Tracks, selected songs from all json file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

im struggling with making queue/mix/playlist function.
My player is working etc, but i want to play selected tracks(10 or so) from all json file(100+).Im getting data that i need (numbers of index for example 5,6,27,33). But i cant really make it work when i want to only them to play. I tried to make it via loops, other nextMusicQueue function, but it didnt work.
Any suggestion with what could i try once again?

```
function clickedQueue(){
  const ids = $('.artist-main-content-item').map((i, el) => el.getAttribute('li-index')).get();
  wrapper.classList.add("list")
  let i = ids[0]; i++;
  indexNumb = i;
  loadMusic(indexNumb);
  playMusic();
  playingSong();
  return ids;
}
```

```
function nextMusic(){

  if (wrapper.classList.contains("list")) {
    var ids = clickedQueue();
      for (let i = idLoaded; i < 2; i++) {
        console.log(ids[i]);
        i++;
        indexNumb = ids[i];
      }
    }

    loadMusic(indexNumb);
    setTimeout(() => {
      playMusic();
    }, 500)
    playingSong();

  }else{
    toggleSequence();
    indexNumb++;
    indexNumb > allMusic.length ? indexNumb = 1 : indexNumb = indexNumb;
    loadMusic(indexNumb);
    setTimeout(() => {
      playMusic();
    }, 500)
    playingSong();
  }
}
```

```
  {
    name: "Legend",
    artist: "Twenty one pilots",
    src: "twentyonepilotsLegend",
    id: 25;
  },
  {
    name: "Leave The City",
    artist: "Twenty one pilots",
    src: "twentyonepilotsLeaveTheCity",
    id: 26;
  },
```

```
<div class="artist-main-content-item" li-index="5" onclick="clickedSingle(this)">
        <img src="images/scaled-and-icy-b-iext104194001.jpg">
        <div class="artist-main-content-item-data">
                <p>Choker</p>
                <span>Twenty one pilots</span>
        </div>
        <div class="artist-main-content-item-premiere">
                <p>2021</p>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="artist-main-content-item" li-index="6" onclick="clickedSingle(this)">
        <img src="images/scaled-and-icy-b-iext104194001.jpg">
        <div class="artist-main-content-item-data">
                <p>The Outside</p>
                <span>Twenty one pilots</span>
        </div>
        <div class="artist-main-content-item-premiere">
                <p>2021</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I got solution for that, i will just change allmusic/musiclist attriubte by filter.x function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for that, i will just change allmusic/musiclist attriubte by filter.x function, and rechange it if it will be needed.

```
  let filterName = artistCardTitle.innerText;
  allMusic = allMusic.filter(x => x.artist === filterName);
  var indexNumb = Math.floor((Math.random() * allMusic.length) + 1);
  wrapper.classList.add("queued")
  loadMusic(indexNumb);
  playMusic();
  playingSong();
}
```